PowerBi Embed in React
Is it possible to pass a value to a <PowerBiEmbed /> as filter so that the values on the report will change?
I have a function where I get numbers inputted by the user and when they enter, it should pass the value to <PowerBiEmbed /> and must change the values of the initial report
According to chatgpt i should do it like this:
<PowerBIEmbed
    embedConfig={{
        type: 'report',
        id: 'id', // Replace with your report ID
        embedUrl: 'url', // Replace with your report's embed URL
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken, // Replace with your access token
        settings: {
            panes: {
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: false
                },
                filters: {
                    expanded: false,
                    visible: false,
                    // Add your filter here
                    filters: [
                        {
                            $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
                            target: {
                                table: "YourTableName", // Replace with your table name
                                column: "columName" // Replace with your column name
                            },
                            operator: "In",
                            values: [
                                "12345" // Replace with the value you want to filter by
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
    eventHandlers={
        new Map([
            ['loaded', function () { console.log('Report loaded'); }],
            ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }]
        ])
    }

    cssClassName="Embed-container"
/>

But it is not working because there is an error that Ifilter does not contain a filter, something like that.

If you still have questions and not clear with the below ans, then your qns should be specific

Yes, You need to pass the filters array in the embedConfig. Check IReportEmbedConfiguration for more details on interface. Refer to this documentation Control Report filters on how to apply filters to the Embedded report.
Since you're using powerbi-client-react package,

you can apply filters during the loading phase by simply passing the filters array in the Embed Config.

const filter: models.IBasicFilter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    filterType: models.FilterType.Basic,
    target: {
        table: "Geo",
        column: "Region"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: ["West", "Central"]
};

const [sampleReportConfig, setReportConfig] = useState<models.IReportEmbedConfiguration>({
        type: 'report',
        embedUrl: <Embed_URL>,
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: <Embed_Token>,
        filters: [filter]: 
    });

Pass the sampleReportConfig to the embedConfig prop of PowerBIEmbed and it will embed the report with the filters you're passing.

Apply filters during the runtime after report gets loaded by simply updating Embed Config. The package detects if there is change in embedConfig and apply updated filters for you.

setReportConfig({
   ...sampleReportConfig,
   filters: [new_filter]
});

Report will get updated with new filters array passed.

Thank you for your response. Im using react typescript when i try doing the code above theres an error in pointing in embedConfig when i add the filters:[filter].
right now my code look slike this:
<PowerBIEmbed
embedConfig = {{ type: 'report',  id: reportId, embedUrl: embedUrl, groupId:groupId, datasetIds: datasetids, permissions: models.Permissions.Read,  accessToken: embeddedToken, tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed, filters: [basicFilter],
}}
/>
//@ts-ignore above filters the error went away but when i try tocheck the report there's no change on the report

Sorry for late reply, I saw you raised this in another question and it was resolved. LMK if problem still exists.
